# How to prevent line breaks in Japanese text

Tags: css, line-breaks, cjk

I have html code

```html
<tr>
    <th>
      勤務開始希望日
    </th>
    <td>
      <input maxlength="250" type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>
```

i want it inline: 勤務開始希望日
but the result is:

> 勤
>   務
>   開
>   始
>   希
>   望
>   日
>
> I don't set max-width or any css for `th` tag.
>   If not Japanese, it work fine. Please help me!

Comment: Can you produce a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue? I put your code in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/y1jc4x5L/), but it works as desired. So in your case, something is going wrong with some code you're not showing.

Comment: this is img of <th> : http://prntscr.com/nlw7rc
i test with another text in another <div>, it fine, just <th> in <table> error

Comment: Do you want *no breaks at all* in that line? Or should it have a certain *minimum width*?

Comment: i want it inline 勤務開始希望日, i can css to fix it but i don't know why there was that error

Answer (score 1):

```css
table {
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      勤務開始希望日
    </th>
    <th>
      Starting date
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As you see, if a table/column is too narrow for some reason or another, line breaks are inserted so as to make the column as narrow as possible. English/Latin text is only broken at spaces (or with very intelligent hyphen-insertion), since it would otherwise become unreadable. Japanese/Chinese text is still perfectly readable when stacked, so it can be broken at any point.

You either want to prevent *all* line breaks:

```css
table {
  width: 10px;
}

th {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      勤務開始希望日
    </th>
    <th>
      Starting date
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or you want to enforce a certain minimum width:

```css
table {
  width: 10px;
}

th {
  min-width: 4em;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      勤務開始希望日
    </th>
    <th>
      Starting date
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: sorry for writing an unknown question, i fixed it, i want it inline 勤務開始希望日, i can css to fix it but i don't know why there was that error

Comment: Again, because the table was trying to conserve space for whatever reason. Without seeing your entire table and the context it's embedded in, nobody can tell you why your table felt particularly width-constrained.